# a dual variable not in statement?

Tags: left-join

I have the need to look at two tables that share two variables and get a list of the data from one table that does not have matching data in the other table.  Example:

Table A

xName
Date
Place
xAmount

Table B

yName
Date
Place
yAmount

I need to be able to write a query that will check Table A and find entries that have no corresponding entry in Table B.  If it was a one variable issue I could use not in statement but I can't think of a way to do that with two variables.  A left join also does not appear like you could do it.  Since looking at it by a specific date or place name would not work since we are talking about thousands of dates and hundreds of place names.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT TableA.Date,
        TableA.Place,
        TableA.xName,
        TableA.xAmount,
        TableB.yName,
        TableB.yAmount
 FROM TableA

 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
 ON TableA.Date = TableB.Date
 AND TableA.Place = TableB.Place

 WHERE TableB.yName IS NULL
 OR TableB.yAmount IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM B 
 WHERE A.xName = B.yName AND A.Date = B.Date AND A.Place = B.Place AND A.xAmount = B.yAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

in ORACLE:

```
select xName , xAmount from tableA
MINUS
select yName , yAmount from tableB
```